# What is the main purpose of continuous testing?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, cicd, continuous-testing

What is the main purpose of continuous testing? How to integrate continous testing tools with ci/cd tools? You should write your qa testing codes(ex. java code with selenium) and integrate it with ci/cd tools(for ex. jenkins) or there is something another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Continuous Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_testing) is the process of executing the automated tests as part of the software delivery pipeline in order to obtain a feedback at the early as possible about the business risks associated with a software release candidate. It evolves and extends test automation to address the increased complexity and pace of modern application development and delivery.

There are quite a few CI/CD tools available to choose from and some of them are:

- *Jenkins*
- *CircleCI*
- *TeamCity*
- *Bamboo*
- *GitLab*
- *Buddy*
- *Travis CI*
- *Codeship*

Comment: what about octopus?